# Javascript Array of audio objects doesnt load the tracks

Tags: javascript, arrays, audio, audio-player

I have a problem with a tracklist created from a folder like that:

```
let tracks = [];
let art_str = [];
let name_str = [];

const traxFolder = './Resto';
const fst = require('fs');

fst.readdirSync(traxFolder).forEach(track => {
    tracks.push(track); 
    name_str.push(track.substring(track.indexOf("-") + 1 ,track.indexOf(".")));
    art_str.push(track.substring(0, track.indexOf("-")));
});

function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    let temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
    }
 }

let track_list = tracks.map ((sng,i) => ({path : `${traxFolder}/${sng}` , 
            name:name_str[i], 
            artist: art_str[i],
            image: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1717969/pexels-photo-1717969.jpeg?
            auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=250&w=250"}));

//shuffleArray(track_list);   
console.log(track_list);
```

the above code creates an array track_list and i can see  all the objects are ok in the console!
when i use this function:

```
let track_index = 0;
let isPlaying = false;
let updateTimer;

let curr_track = document.createElement('audio');

function loadTrack(list_index) {
clearInterval(updateTimer);
resetValues();
curr_track.src = track_list[list_index].path;
curr_track.load();
}

loadTrack(track_index);
```

it doesnt load the track of index zero or any track_index i try 1,2,3 etc.
while the same exact code workd perfect if the array track_list comes in this form:

```
let track_list = [
{
    name: "Clear As Water",
    artist: "Una Mas Trio",
    image: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2264753/pexels-photo-2264753etcetc 
    path:  "resto/Una Mas Trio - Clear As Water (Hidden Jazz Quartet Remix).mp3"
},
{
    name: "Mango Woman",
    artist: "Mo Horizons",
    image: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3100835/pexels-photo-etcetc
    path: "musiclists/Mo Horizons - Mango Woman.mp3"
},
{
    name: "Invitation To Dance (Vincemo Hang Sessions Mix)",
    artist: "Monotone",
    image: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1717969/pexels-etc etc
    path: "musiclists/Monotone-Invitation To Dance (Vincemo Hang Sessions Mix).mp3",
},
];
```

Can anyone tell me why the first array does not seem to load any track while the second does
when the only difference IN THE CODE is the way the array track_list is created , WHILE THE OBJECT PROPERTIES ARE IDENTICAL?

Thanks and Regards to everyone

Comment: what does your `resetValues()` function does?

Comment: function resetValues() {
  curr_time.textContent = "00:00";
  total_duration.textContent = "00:00";
  seek_slider.value = 0;
}

Comment: Still though the array that all objects are set manually works and the one that reads the folder doesn't!the rest of the code is the same..i don't have too much understanding in the underlying mechanics..i am just learning now..also both arrays have exact same print in the console with the same properties name,artist,path and image.

Comment: I would highly recommend lowercasing and substituting spaces for `_` in your audio files to avoid potential path problems

Comment: This gets even weirder..i took your advice and i copy the array that the function prints from the console window in vs code from another java script  file and it loads the tracks fine as an array of objects..that guarranted the path etc..if then i replaced again the code with the for each function that creates the array and it doesn't!!!so the array as objects from the function works..the function that generates the array does not!